# Android apps do not trust my CA in the system store

Tags: android, ssl, fiddler, ca, sniffing

I am trying to intercept the Opera browser (for example) on Android 8.1 as a first step to sniffing another app for which i am coding a custom backend. I do not want to recompile the apk so I installed Magisk and the "Always Trust User Certificates" module, tath I subsequently enabled.

I have exported my CA certificate and installed it as a user certificate. I then rebooted and I can see it in the System CA list.

Yet, when I browse to https://example.com I get a (basic) invalid certificate error.

This happens to all applications. My deduction is that somehow apps don't trust the systemless CA.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On modern Android, apps must opt-in to user certificates: https://textslashplain.com/2016/07/27/using-fiddler-with-ios-10-and-android-7/

Comment: Using that magisk module my Root CA appears in the system certificates list